# List index out of range

Tags: python, list

I have written a program that makes sure each cookie has more than 5 chips before moving on.
However, the line `if cookie[i] > 5:` seems to be problematic, as it produces a "list index out of range" error. I thought `foo = []` created a list with no ending, so I don't get why *any* number would be out of range in this list. What am I doing wrong?

```
cookie = []

...

for i in range(0, 11):
    if cookie[i] > 5:
         break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
len(cookie)
```

You'll see if you haven't put anything in it that it'll be size 0. With `cookie = []` you can continuously add elements to the list but it's initialized empty.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
cookies = []

...

for cookie in cookies:
    if cookie > 5:
         break
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really have a list with no ending that in your case presumably has only zeros in it.

You can however create a list with  11  zeros:

```
cookies = [0] * 11
```

Or create something that returns `0` if you access it at an index if you haven't put anything else in there:

```
import collections
cookies = collections.defaultdict(int)
```

Note that this is not a list but a map.

Answer (score 1):

`foo = []` creates an *empty* list, not a list with no ending. Any index access will fail on an empty list. To check the length of a list, use `len(mylist)`. The length of an empty list is 0, and indices are zero-based. So:

```
cookie = []
len(cookie) == 0
cookie[0] ## will raise IndexError

cookie.append('something')
len(cookie) == 1
cookie[0] ## will return 'something'
```

See the [list docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 1):

`cookie = []` creates empty list with no data, so no indexes here.  You need to fill `cookie` with some data first (e.g. using `cookie.append(some_data)`).

Answer (score 1):

`foo=[]` does not create a list with no ending.  Instead, it creates an empty list.

You could do

```
for i in range(0, len(foo)):
    if(cookie[i]>5):
        break
```

Or you could do

```
for c in cookie:
    if c>5:
        break
```